# Cycles Normal Baking adding strange dents and bumps

Tags: normals, baking, normal-map

I keep getting a strange cavities near the seam lines in my mesh. I've tried everything I can think of to fix the issues including massaging the area with the smooth brush to relax vert, messing with the cage ranges, unsubing the mutlires, and scaling the low poly. I still keep getting these weird issues. I'm hoping someone might have an answer because I'm sure it's something silly on the user error side! [image] Thank you for any help. I'm at my whits end trying to figure this out. The only thing I have left would be to take it to PS to clean up.

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.